# Swift Firebase Database get data

Tags: swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have Firebase cloud structure:

[image]

How can I catch name of `firstBook` and `secondBook` and write to the array

And create another array with quotes(Quote1+ Qoute2+ Quote3) from `firstbook`

I'm try this :

```
var array: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Database.database().reference().ref?.child("category").child("book").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let valueCat = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        let username = valueCat["name"] as? String ?? ""
        print(username)
        self.array.append(username)
    }
}
```

To another array :

```
var quotAarray: [String] = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Database.database().reference().ref?.child("category").child("book").child("firstBook").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
        let valueCat = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

        let quote = valueCat["Quotes"] as? String ?? ""
        print(quote)
        self.quotAarray.append(quote)
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is issue ? are you not getting Username?

Comment: @iOSGeek , Yes, I cant get username

Comment: @iOSGeek, if I print(snapshot.value) it give me : `Optional({
    firstBook =     {
        Quotes =         {
            Quote1 = 1111;
            Quote2 = 222;
            Quote3 = 333;
        };
        name = firs;
    };
    name = book;
    secondBook =     {
        Quote =         {
            Quote1 = 111;
            Quote2 = 222;
            Quote3 = 333;
        };
        name = secondBook;
    };
})`

Comment: @iOS Geek, Can you help me with this? Maybe somewhere I can read about it?

Comment: Okay I will look into it, Need to fetch name Right ?

Comment: @iOSGeek, Yes every name from books, If books are not static they can be added later  ( from  firstBook name +  secondBook name + ...)

Comment: why your child have different Names? quotes in firstBook then Quote in secondBook ? Are you manually adding Data ?

Comment: @iOSGeek , this is mistake, there's all the intentions will be Quote

Comment: Try checking I posted an answer with full Explanation as per my understanding , let me know if it suits your case and helps you getting Data

Comment: @iOSGeek, Yes, it's works)

Comment: output came in your Project ?

Comment: @iOSGeek, yes I'm get output

Comment: Glad to know, if my answer helped you accept it and you can close this thread, Thanks

Comment: @iOSGeek Thank you

Comment: Happy to help , welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this helps you I made a sample Dictionary as per your response received

Code used:

```
/// Sample Data on Base of your Output SHown
var DBData = [["firstBook":["Quotes": ["Quote1":111, "Quote2":222, "Quote3":333 ], "name":"first_Book"]], ["SecondBook":["Quotes":["Quote1":111,"Quote2":222,"Quote3":333],"name":"Second_Book"]]]

/// Names Array - In which book names need to be added
var nameArray = [String]()

/// For loop on base of DBData as it Array of Array Data
for i in 0..<DBData.count {
    /// Assumed You have only one Main key in each array
    /// Can be known before .
    /// if you do not know Let's get keys here in Array at index i
    let keysArray : [String] = Array(DBData[i].keys)

    /// Now get the current dict value on base of key retrieved as in
    /// first case its - firstBook
    /// Second case its - SecondBook
    let currentDictValue = DBData[i][keysArray[0]]

    /// Now get Names of books
    /// name is the key used in your DB its generic and its fixed
    /// Now get value and add in Array
    nameArray.append(currentDictValue!["name"] as! String)
}

/// Output
print("Name Array:\(nameArray)")
```

Final output:

[image]

**Note** use either Quotes or Quote , Keys should be similar in DB

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 let valueCat = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
 if let firstBook = valueCat["firstBook"] as? NSDictionary {
     print(firstBook["name"])
 }
```

To get all book names you have to iterate through the childs

Comment: Through all childs?  Can I get names from all book( firstBook+ secondBook)? And make universal code, for example if I go to film to show all the films names?

Comment: The names of books, films... are not static, they will always increase. Can I do this?